# Touchscreen on Lenovo Yoga 520 and Gnome

Tags: gnome, xorg, 17.04, wacom, wayland

Following problem: I bought a Lenovo Yoga 520-14IKB 80X8 and tried to use it with the Gnome DE. I wanted to use the build-in Wacom touchscreen, so i did not choose Gnome on wayland, because it lacks wacom support.

Under Gnome (Xorg) the Pen and digitizer seem to work, but the Touchscreen is a bit freaky. The touchscreen is recognized as a mouse device and thus does not support the Gnome touch gestures.
Now I face the following dilemma: Use Gnome on Wayland for the touch gestures or Xorg for the pen but without the gestures. **Any Idea of how to enable the gestures in XOrg?**

([this](https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/335/) - seems to describe a similar, if not the same, problem - unfortunately the fix didn't work for me)

---

**Specs:**

*Software:*

Ubuntu 17.04, Gnome 3.24

*Hardware:*

Laptop: Lenovo Yoga 520-14IKB 80X8

Touchscreen: Wacom HID 50DE (Pen, and Touch)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `xinput`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue here. Active stylus, single touch is working, but multitouch gestures aren't.

---

**Specs:**

*Software:*

Ubuntu 18.10, Gnome 3.30.1

*Hardware:*

Slate: Lenovo Miix 520 12IKB

Touchscreen: Wacom HID 513B (pen & touch)

---

### Update:

I've solved the issue by disabling Wacom built-in gestures:

`$ xsetwacom set "Wacom HID 513B Finger touch" Gesture off`

Replace device name in "" with your own.

You can find it in:

`$ xsetwacom --list devices`

Pick the one with type: TOUCH.

Let me know if it helps!